# How to generate pytorch models randomly?

Tags: python, pytorch, model

I want to get a lot of models to run a benchmark. I am hoping to generate those models randomly, which will contains many different layers(conv2d, batchnorm, lstm,etc...). However, Considering the relationship between the input of the previous layer and the output of the next layer, it's hard to implement in s simple program.
So is there some way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot even begin to imagine why you would ever want to do this, nevertheless here is my approach.

1. Go through PyTorch documentation, pick some layers, and write down their input and output shapes
2. Create a graph, where each node contains

   - Name of the `nn.Module`
   - Function that transforms the input shape to the output shape
   - Possible additional arguments
3. Edges are between nodes that have compatible input and output shapes
4. Do a random traversal, create a `nn.Module` on each visit, and append them to a list
5. Use this list to create the model with `nn.ModuleList`

I mean *Graph* in the abstract sense, you can implement it with lists or dictionaries.